# How to call useQuery api only if token exists in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am totally new to react js, I could not understand now why it throws

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
```

Trying to achieve,

- In header component, if token exists, then call useQuery api to check the token is valid in server side,
- if it is valid, then set state

**header.jsx**

```
  const [isUserExists, setIsUserExists] = useState();      //if valid token, then set true
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");            //if valid token, then set userName, which is return from api call 
  const [isEnabledApi, setIsEnabledApi] = useState(false)  //call useQuery only once ,if it is true
```

at first I need to check token exists or not,
here is the problem I found, I commented all the lines except `setIsEnabledApi(true);`, then error throws. **why?**

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("Token");
if(token){
    console.log('token exists')
    setIsEnabledApi(true); //allow to call api, to check user exists or not
             //setIsEnabledApi(true); this line making infinite re-render error
}
else{
    console.log('token exists')
    setIsEnabledApi(false); //don't allow to call api, to check user exists or not   
}
```

now I am calling `apiAuth`

```
    const result = apiAuth(setIsUserExists,isEnabledApi,setIsEnabledApi,setUserName);
    console.log('api RESULT = '+result)
    console.log(result.data)
```

if user logged in true, then my jsx

```
return(
    <>
        {isUserExists? <UserButton> : <LoginButton }
    </>
)
```

in **apiAuth.js**

```
export const apiAuth = (setIsUserExists,isEnabledApi,setIsEnabledApi,setUserName) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['isUserExist'],
    queryFn: () => {
        console.log('calling query function')
        return IsLoggedIn() // axios.get("/Auth");

    },

    enabled: isEnabledApi,     //it will decider either will call api or not

    onSuccess: (loginInfo) => {
      console.log("user Logged IN Success");

      console.log(loginInfo);

      if (loginInfo) {
        console.log("User Exists");
        console.log(loginInfo);
        setIsUserExists(true);
        setIsEnabledApi(false);  // dont call this api anymore

        setUserName(loginInfo.data.userName)
        return loginInfo;
      }
    },
    onError: () => {
      console.log("Logged In Failed");
      setIsEnabledApi(false);
      setIsUserExists(false);
      
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: If you call `setIsEnabledApi(true)` in the scope of the function component, it will cause an infinite loop.